# SFDX Test Cases Failing only on Package Version Create

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, failing-tests, unmanaged-package

EDIT: If you are using a CI flow, ensure that it isn't creating profiles for you when running test cases. That was the main issue for me when using cumulusci.

I am trying to deploy a package version from an unmanaged package and all the test cases are failing only during the `sfdx force:package:version:create` command. I have a sneaking suspicion it is due to a `@TestSetup` annotated method that isn't called during the package testing, but I couldn't find anything documented about it.

EDIT: Error message I am getting is,

```
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  Apex Test Failure: Class.CaseDetailsTest.allCaseDetails: line 68, column 1 System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 2, Actual: 0,Apex Test Failure: Class.CaseDetailsTest.myCaseDetails: line 86, column 1 System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 2, Actual: 0,Apex Test Failure: Class.CaseDetailsTest.last7Days: line 104, column 1 System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 1, Actual: 0,Apex Test Failure: Class.CaseDetailsTest.last30Days: line 122, column 1 System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 2, Actual: 0
```

EDIT 2: Class being tested (As this is a private project, I've simplified the implementation to the main query)

```
public static CaseDetails getDetails(
        Id contactId, Integer offset, String[] filters, Boolean showAudit
    ){
        query = 'SELECT Id, ' +
            'Name ' +
        'FROM Case_Detail__c ' +
        'WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED '+
        'WHERE Case__r.ContactId = \'' + contactId + '\' ';
        details = Database.query(query);
        return this;
    }
... additional implementation hidden, but just adds query filters.
```

EDIT 3: I have updated my post with the relevant information for any other people getting this problem.

Comment: What’s the failure message?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I updated my post with the error message.

Comment: Share the class CaseDetails ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I've updated my post with a simplified version of the class, I don't see why the implementation of the class would fail during just package creation though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to solve this issue, the problem was the SFDX integration tool I was using, CumulusCI. It was creating a profile that allowed all `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED` queries to run with no issue.

The solution was to create a new permission setand then assign a user to that permission set, then use that user to run the tests.

```
User runningUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email = 'EMAIL' LIMIT 1];
PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'NAME'];
insert new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = runningUser.id, PermissionSetId = ps.Id);
System.runAs(runningUser){
...
```