# Getting an error while creating unlocked package with --codecoverage option in salesforce

Tags: managed-package, code-coverage, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, unlocked-package

As per the current requirement new versions of packages can be created only buy running the **sfdx force:package:version:create** with --codecoverage option, however I am getting an exception related to field level access while executing SOQL queries(I have field level access check before running SOQL in my apex code)  when I run the following command. The below command works find without --codecoverage option, however I am not able to promote the package without running create command with codecoverage option. The user which I am using has sysadmin profile and it has all the access to custom objects and fields.

`sfdx force:package:version:create -p MyApp -d force-app --wait 10 -v vscodeOrg --codecoverage`

Comment: If there's an error compile time(not directly may be at executing test classes) then I don't think it'll allow you to create a package.

Comment: there are no errors related to compile, as per the stack trace in the out of command, for example "Apex Test Failure: Class.MyDashboardUtility.getItems: line 50, column 1" is the line number where I throw an exception if field level access is missing for the user. As per this post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319613/test-is-failing-while-creating-package-but-passes-in-all-other-cases, the tests are run in a brand new org and it requires additional meta about custom objects and filed access. How I can create this meta and move it to that org dynamically while running command